# What is the term for a value that is directly dependent upon other values?

Tags: terminology, philosophy, python

Say you have variables A and B, both of which express a certain quantity. Now let's say you have X, which equals the sum of A and B. For example, A = 10, B = 5, and X = 15 because 10 + 5 = 15. The value of A and B can change, so if A = 2, X = 7. So the value of X can also change, but only by the extension of a change in the value of one of the variables contributing to the value of X. In other words, A and B can 'freely' change, but X is 'locked' if you will.

To give a real-world example, let us say that A and B represent a number of Apples. If A = 10a, and B = 5a, and X equals the number of total apples. However, unlike values A and B, we can't really perform maths with the variable X to derive values significant of the real world, you can't take X and add it to A and state that we now have 15 + 10 apples. Mathematically no laws have been broken, but in terms of applied maths, this is not allowed, because you can't just create 15 apples from thin air. So whereas A and B would represent real-world objects, value X is more an abstract value that's derived from the sum of two other values.

My first thought was to call X a reference to A and B, but you could say that A and B are referencing a number of apples. Abstractions is another term, but you could also say A and B are abstractions of real-world quantities, in place for them, where X is an abstraction from abstractions A and B.  Maybe 'free variables' and 'locked variables' would be better? Though am not too sure.

Comment: If I understand correctly, in many cases, you would call $A$ and $B$ as being independent variables and $X$ as being a dependent variable, with it being dependent on $A$ and $B$ in this case. However, it seems you might be looking for a different terminology than this.

Comment: Actually that might be a good word choice. In fact, that might actually be what I was just talking about but without knowing it. I'll look into it right now actually.

Comment: Although on some reflection I guess you typically only have one independent variable and one dependent variable (or maybe several), wherein my circumstance you could have many variables representing real-world data and variables representing derivations from those variables. So on second thought maybe the terms independent and dependent variables are too much of a reserved term for what am looking for.

Comment: Perhaps dependent/independent is not you're looking for, but note that from my experience, there's no "typical" in terms of the number of dependent and/or independent variables. It's definitely possible to have, for example, $2$ independent variables and just $1$ dependent one. However, regardless of what terms you determine you will use, I hope you find some which work very well for you in your situations.

Comment: Thank you, I actually might use independent/dependent since it does seem to fit the Criteria ^_^

Comment: If you said "$X$ is a function of $A$ and $B$", then, depending on the context, your intended meaning might be understood. But, in some sense, this isn't how variables are used in mathematics. The fact that your question is tagged "python" makes me think your variables are Python variables, which act and are spoken about differently than math variables. If that's the case, MSE might not even be the right forum, depending on the context in which you'll be describing this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're describing is just a mere illusion. You CAN change the total number of apple, by putting more apple in. It will force one, or both, variables to change, depending on how you do it.

To make this analogy clearer, imagine you're talking apples held by 2 people. Can you manipulate directly the number of apples held by someone? You might say yes, just give them apples, but I can argue that no, you're just changing the amount of apples hold on their specific hand, and that indirectly cause the total apple hold by that person to change.

In the end, what you have is just a relation: A+B=X. Or to write it in a more symmetrical manner: (1)A+(1)B+(-1)X=0. Three variables and a single relation between them. The 3 are dependent on each other by a single relation.

But there are terms like "independent variable" and "dependent variable" isn't it? These terms applies to the specific procedure (of doing experiment, etc.). Here there is some quantities that you can manipulate freely and monitor so that it has a specific value you want, they're called independent variable, while some other quantities are merely passively measured for their the value, they're called dependent variable. These terms refer to how you treat these quantities in your procedure: the one you set to specific values, or the one you just record.

So outside of that context, when you just have variables floating in empty space, such distinction no longer work. These are just a bunch of variables that dependent on each other by some relationships.